# Android SMS App

Tags: android

How difficult would it be to build an android app that responds to all SMS from a certain number.

Given a certain regexp on those SMS responds with an answer to a certain number.

Example input: "HelloWorld 12345"

Example regexp: "([0-9]{5})"

Example output confif: "Purchase $2"

Should give "Purchase 12345"

Is this possible to build on Android? Is there perhaps already an app for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On prima facie, this seems *doable* on Android.

There is a mechanism and enough API support to intercept incoming SMS and read them: you just have to use a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` Intent action and then use the `SmsMessage.getMessageBody()` to read the message text. Use `SmsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress()` to get the Sender's detail.

There are lots of tutorials on the web that can help you get started. For instance, take a look at [this](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/) and [this](http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html)